# GWT - spring security - session timeout

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I have a GWT + Spring Security web app. I was trying to add:

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/X.html"/>
```

However, when I try to test this. It seems I see a:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.InvocationException
```

with message as the HTML content of X.html. Can someone please advise on how to fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? GWT communicates with the server via ajax RPC calls, it will not redirect your browser to X.html.

Comment: I was actually expecting to get redirected to the login page - for example - X.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because GWT communicates with a server via Ajax RPC requests, the browser will not be redirected to `X.html`. What you need to do in your service calls is throw an exception if they are not authorized and handle in in `void onFailure(Throwable caught)` method of your `AsyncCallback`.

Comment: Do you know why InvocationException's message is the html content of X.html when GWT does a Ajax RPC request?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to /X.html try:

```
Window.Location.replace(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"X.html");
```

However, if you want to send the request  to the server use RequestBuilder:

```
String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "/X.html";

RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

try {
    Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        // invalid request
    }

    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
            // success
        } else {
            // sth went wrong
        }
    }
});
} catch (RequestException e) {
  // couldn't connect to server
}
```